# I use an array as parameter and I receive an observer

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, system.reactive

I'm need this array as a parameter but when I try to use it, I only receive a observer. How to use the information of the array instead of the observer?
When I console.log in the function that retrieves the information from the DB it shows the data as it should. 
I don't know what else to do, I've already tried other ways to try to solve this but I wasn't sucessfull.

```
           <script>
            import { ClientTable } from 'vue-tables-2';
            import Vue from 'vue';
            import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect';
            import options from './../../../commons/helpers/grid.config';
            import edit from './edit';

            Vue.use(ClientTable, options, false, 'bootstrap4', 'default');
            Vue.component('multiselect', Multiselect);

            export default {
              name: 'Reporting',
              removable: false,
              components: {
                edit,
              },
              showLoading: true,
              data() {
                return {
                  selected: null,
                  columns: ['period', 'costCenter', 'hours', 'actions'],
                  reportingsList: [],
                  periods: [],
                  totalHours: 0,
                  options: {
                    sortable: [],
                    columnsClasses: {
                      actions: 'action-column text-center',
                      period: 'period-column',
                      costCenter: 'costCenter-Column',
                      hours: 'hours-column',
                    },
                  },
                };
              },
              mounted() {
                this.getAll();
              },
              methods: {
                getTotalHours(reportings) {
                  let result = 0;
                  for (let i = 0, length = reportings.length; i < length; i += 1) {
                    result += reportings[i].hours;
                  }
                  console.log(result); //eslint-disable-line
                  console.log(this.reportingsList); //eslint-disable-line
                  this.totalHours = result;
                },
                getAll() {
                  const url = 'reportings/getAll';

                  this.$http().get(url).then((response) => {
                    this.reportingsList = response.data;
                    console.log(this.reportingsList.length);//eslint-disable-line
                  });
                  this.getTotalHours(this.reportingsList);
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: I would recommend you cut some of the irrelevant lines from your code, so that we can focus on exactly where the problem is (probably just a few lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's asynchronous code, `this.getTotalHours` will be execute before `this.$http.get` finish.

You need to chain `.then`

```
 this.$http().get(url).then((response) => {
    this.reportingsList = response.data;
    console.log(this.reportingsList.length);//eslint-disable-line
    return response.data
  }).then(() => {
    this.getTotalHours(this.reportingsList);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm new to this and you helped a lot!